# A Inquiry About Infinitive-To and Its Role As A Subordinator or An Auxiliary

Tags: infinitives, inflectional-morphology

If you're interested in grammar, as I am, I am sure you have delved into a thought process about **infinitive to**, and like me, you have probably questioned what it is, or what it could be defined as. My mind always wants to place it in the Eight Parts of Speech, and I know this is foolish of me to some regard, so I stray from it, but I still wish to designate it under something that can be explain it. So, this is the motivation for this post, this question: ***What is the infinitive to, and why?***

Here are my thoughts: There are three real possibilities, going back through the times. First, we can say that it is part of the verb that comes after it (to go, to run, etc.). This could be supported by the claim that you are not supposed to "split" infinitives ("To boldly go"), but only that.

Secondly, we could consider it a subordinator. I came across this designation most recently in my studies of modern and transformational grammar. As of right now, it is still the one I accept, especially as a result of the trend of designating more phrases as clauses. It works, except it's weird. Do we call this a unique subordinator as a result of how it operates? For example, to-infinitive clauses call for non-finite verb forms, which typically have an implied subject as a part of their clause. For example, "I want to go **to the store**." In the infinitive clause, "I" is the implied subject, as a understand. So, again, this works. However, things get a little weird when other subordinators come into play. For example, "I'm excited for you to win the competition." Now, if I'm right, those of you will say that "for" is a preposition here, as a result of the new-grammar stuff, but I'm going to count it as a subordinator, as defined by my own beliefs and that of a lot of other grammars. So, how do the clauses work in such a sentence? According to transformational grammar, "for you to win the competition" is defined as an **ordinary** clause. So, does that mean that it also contains a secondary clause within itself (the infinitive clause part)? If so, how do those two clauses work in conjunction to each other when one is so integrated? "For you to win the competition" looks to just be one clause, but if that's the case, doesn't "to" have to represent something else?

This moves us on to the third way to look at things, which is to consider "to" as auxiliary verb, a defective one at that. There are a lot of things to support this, and it even allows for the split infinitive. Furthermore, it calls for a non-finite verb form to follow, like an auxiliary. But, as I said before, it's defective in the way that is all it can function as.

As I said, I still accept **to** as a subordinator, but I want to be proven wrong or right. Wrong by showing evidence of it being something else, or right by showing how clauses operate when it seems to be layered up.

Comment: It certainly can't be an auxiliary verb. And it's clearly not attached to the verb, so the second alternative is the only choice. "Subordinator", though, is a very general term -- prepositions like _to_ and _for_ are subordinators, for instance, and so are conjunctions like _if_. The actual technical term for the _to_ of infinitives is that it's a **Complementizer** (very clunky name; sorry about that), because it introduces a complement clause. Infinitive clauses are mostly complement clauses, you see. The full complementizer includes _for_ to mark the subject, and _to_ for the verb.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you for the reply. I think I've read one of your papers before actually. Was it where you said that sentences like "I want to ride the horse" can be derivative or "I want for me to ride the horse"? Sort of a omission-type scenario?

Comment: Yes, that would be the rule of Equi-NP-Deletion; the subject of _ride_ is redundant since it's also the subject of _want_, so it's deleted by rule. When the subject is deleted, we don't need the _for_ introducing it either. Since infinitive subjects are normally deleted or raised, _for_ isn't a part of most infinitives. Unless they begin a sentence, when the _for_ is required: _For him to leave would be a mistake_ versus *_Him to leave would be a mistake_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Ahh, this is very intriguing stuff.It makes me question "to" even more. It's almost like there is a hidden "for" subordinating conjunction in these scenarios-- or actually, any scenario with the to-infinitive. But then, as you said, it can be chipped away at more when the subject of the infinitive clause is the same as the main subject. I wonder, however, in constructions where the to-infinitive clause is a noun clause without a main subject to fall on. "To go to the store would be a mistake." Would that equal something like "For anyone to go to the store would be a mistake"?

Comment: There's a _for_ **Complementizer**, not a subordinating conjunction. Subordinating conjunctions are a different kind of subordinator. And, yes, the infinitive complementizer is officially called "the _for..to_ complementizer"; both the _for_ and the _to_ can get deleted themselves, but deleting the _for_ is much more common than deleting the _to_, which only happens after certain verbs and in certain constructions. The deleted "For anyone" subject is called an indefinite subject, and it's often just marked as `Indef` because the other information about it is, um, not definite.

Comment: @JohnLawler I have a love-hate relationship with changing grammar, but I do not reject it. However, I will ask, where did "for...to" lie in traditional grammar, before the rise of the mighty and mysterious _complementizer_?

Comment: It didn't lie anywhere, because traditional grammar was about Latin, not English, and Latin didn't have (or at least didn't notice) any complementizers. After all, it was the 4th century; you're not dealing with modern science here. Hell, they didn't even notice adjectives.

Comment: @JohnLawler How new are complementizers? Surely, there was a time when you yourself didn't have the term to use. I could imagine some people just throwing it in the conjunction category.

Comment: @JohnLawler And, going back to the discussion at hand, with these infinitive clauses, we have established that there can be implied subjects and hidden complementizers ("hidden" used loosely). Plus, we do indeed call these clauses, and not phrases, these days. But, I wonder, if these are tucked so tightly to main sentence clause and can still be considered clauses, what is there to say about other non-finite forms, such as participles? "I am running fast" Is this still just one main clause, or does the non-finite verb "running" represent a smaller, tightly integrated sub-clause?

Comment: It's best treated as a **subordinator** functioning as a **marker** for the VPs of infinitival clauses. It derives historically from the preposition "to" (notice the strong similarity between _I went to the doctor_ and _I went to see the doctor_), but long ago it lost its prepositional properties. Consider also the clause subordinator "for", again a marker, but for _to_-infinitivals that contain a subject.

Comment: You are right about "I am running fast". Traditionally "am running" has been taken as a constituent (and commonly called 'the  verb'). There was a lot of argument about this in the 70s, and many have come round to the view that the auxiliary verbs are special cases of catenative verbs. This is the view taken by H&P in their CGEL, the finest grammar available today.

Comment: @BillJ I understand that it is a catenative verb, allowing for the non-finite verb "running" to follow in chain, but does that mean it has a second clause, or do we understand this as one?

Comment: @BillJ Additionally, as per some research I just did, I found that the similarities between subject/object raising verbs and auxiliary are astounding, to the point where the arguments for contrast are not enough. So, that again goes towards my question about the clause layering. Obviously, in a sentence such as “I want to run to the store” we are dealing with a subordinate clause starting with infinitive to, but again, what about something like “I am running”?

Comment: @AllexKramer Yes, "running" is a separate subordinate clause. Thus "I am running" is a matrix clause with "running" as catenative complement.

Comment: @BillJ For once, I prefer a new analysis. Thank you!

Comment: @BillJ Before I write a recap answer to this question, in the structures that contain "for" and "to", can we again consider each of them subordinating a lower level clause, even though the subject of both is pretty explicit? For example,

"I want for you to come with me."

"For" subordinator leads its own clause.
"To" contains an even lower one.


Or, would it be better to simply say that "For" and "To" work together on the same level? If that's the case, then I think structures like "You are to go with me" cannot be explained since the "for" isn't even there at all.

Answer (score -1):

My first instinct is to consider the infinitive "to" as one of the eight parts of speech it usually is: a preposition or adverb.

If prepositions modify nouns and pronouns, and adverbs modify adverbs, adjectives, and verbs, isn't the infinitive "to" simply an adverb?

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, I don't think we can call "to" adverbial, especially since it is so obligatory when it appears in an infinitive.